# Self-Registration Communities

Tags: visualforce, community, partner-portal

I enabled self-registration and am using a custom visualforce login page for my communities. 
How do i add a "Sign Up" or "Register" button on my custom vf login page?

Comment: Have you looked at the default `Self-Register` page and controller?

Answer (score 0):

Use the CommunitiesSelfRegistration Visualforce Page and Controller as a reference.  Keep in mind the test coverage is a bit of a pain on this as well :)

You'll need to make sure you have a Site.com setup and give the Site.com Guest User access to the pages needed for Self-Registration.